# How to get pipe string length?

Tags: string, shell, pipe

This is a code that shows my all user names.

```
-q user | grep -A 0 -B 2 -e uid:\ 5'[0-9][0-9]' | grep ^name | cut -d " " -f2-
```

For example, the output is like...

```
usernameone
hello
whoami
```

Then, I hope that I want to check a length of all user names.
Like this output...

```
11 //usernameone
5 //hello
6 //whoami
```

How can I get a length of pipeline code?

Comment: `....| awk '{print length($0) "\t" $0}'` .... Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Given some command `cmd` that produces the list of users, you can do this pretty easily with `xargs`:

```sh
$ cat x
usernameone
hello
whoami
$ cat x | xargs -L 1 sh -c 'printf "%s //%s\n" "$(echo -n "$1" | wc -c)" "$1"' '{}'
11 //usernameone
5 //hello
6 //whoami
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a piped command might not be possible, so here's a one liner that uses a split and a while loop to accomplish this:

```
-q user | grep -A 0 -B 2 -e uid:\ 5'[0-9][0-9]' | grep ^name | cut -d " " -f2-|tr " " "\n"|while read user; do echo $(echo $user|wc -c) '//'$user;done|tr "\n" " ";echo
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an output in the desired format. I used `user` as a file hence the `cat`

```
i=0;for token in $(cat user); do echo -n "${#token} //$token";echo;i=$((i+1));done;echo;
```